# Authtoken migration not working despite unit test functioning

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations, auth-token

I'm adding [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) to our django project.  All was going well, and I've added a migration and unit test for the token auth:

```
# Migration
from django.db import migrations


def create_missing_tokens(apps, schema_editor):
    """
    Tokens were added in 0002_auto_20160226_1747, we thus need to populate
    the tokens table for existing users
    """
    Token = apps.get_model('authtoken', 'Token')
    User = apps.get_model('accounts', 'CustomUser')
    for user in User.objects.all():
        Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # depends on authtoken migration
        ('accounts', '0003_subscription_max_updates_per_day'),
        ('authtoken', '0002_auto_20160226_1747'), # latest migration in the authtoken package
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_missing_tokens, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

```
# unit test
class MigrationTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    '''A Test case for testing migrations'''

    # These must be defined by subclasses.
    migrate_from = None
    migrate_to = None

    def setUp(self):
        super(MigrationTestCase, self).setUp()

        self.executor = MigrationExecutor(connection)
        self.executor.migrate(self.migrate_from)

    def migrate_to_dest(self):
        self.executor.loader.build_graph()  # reload.
        self.executor.migrate(self.migrate_to)

    @property
    def old_apps(self):
        return self.executor.loader.project_state(self.migrate_from).apps

    @property
    def new_apps(self):
        return self.executor.loader.project_state(self.migrate_to).apps

from accounts.models import CustomUserManager
class SummaryTestCase(MigrationTestCase):
    """
    We need to test that data is populated in the summary field on running the migration
    """

    migrate_from = [('accounts', '0003_subscription_max_updates_per_day')]
    migrate_to = [('accounts', '0004_create_tokens')]

    def setup_before_migration(self):
        manager = CustomUserManager()
        User = self.old_apps.get_model('accounts', 'CustomUser')
        manager.model = User
        manager.create_user(email='contact@a.fr',  # nosec
                            password='kjnfrkj',
)

    def test_token_populated(self):
        # runs setup
        self.setup_before_migration()

        # now migrate
        self.migrate_to_dest()

        # grab new models
        Token = self.new_apps.get_model('authtoken', 'Token')
        User = self.new_apps.get_model('accounts', 'CustomUser')
        for user in User.objects.all():
            self.assertTrue(Token.objects.filter(user_id=user.pk).exists())
```

This works great, but when i actually run the migration i get the message:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "authtoken_token_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (key)=() already
>   exists.

Here is some pseudo code for what i mean by "actually run the migration":

```
$ git checkout <old commit>          # grab old commit
$ ./run.sh go                        # spin up docker with server and db
$ git checkout master                # which includes migrations
$ ./run.sh again                     # log into docker image with django
$ (docker) python manage.py migrate  # run the migrations
```

the error i see is thus (full stack trace at the end of the question):

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "authtoken_token_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (key)=() already exists.
```

I cant understand how with a migration that uses `Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)` I'm getting a duplicate key?  any help would be greatly appreciated

```
  Applying accounts.0004_create_tokens...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 538, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
__fake__.DoesNotExist: Token matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "authtoken_token_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (key)=() already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 190, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/code/accounts/migrations/0004_create_tokens.py", line 12, in create_missing_tokens
    Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 541, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(kwargs, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 583, in _create_object_from_params
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 575, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1335, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "authtoken_token_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (key)=() already exists.
```

EDIT: Custom user class is nothing special, looks like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """
    Replace username by email as required and unique.
    """
    is_alphanumeric_or_dash = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z\-]*$', 'Only alphanumeric and "-" characters are allowed.')

    # Hide username
    username = None

    # Overidde other fields
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'),
                                  max_length=100,
                                  blank=True,
                                  validators=[is_alphanumeric_or_dash])
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'),
                                 max_length=100,
                                 blank=True,
                                 validators=[is_alphanumeric_or_dash])

    # /!\ At some point, user should have a default subcription /!\
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    # some other fields, but nothing special...
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # Override the UserManager with our custom one (for objects creation)
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Comment: What does your `CustomUser` class look like?

Comment: I'd guess that your db somehow got horked while you were setting things up.  Have you tried opening a shell and examining the existing `Token` objects?

Comment: @Ben updated the question, thanks for the interest

Comment: I'm suspect that `username = None` is a problem. But I don't have any conclusive answers.  I guess I would also look at things like:  
*1.* AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser' ,  *2.* INSTALLED_APPS setup correctly , *3.* making sure `python manage.py drf_create_token <username>` works

Answer (score 2):

A `Token`'s key is normally generated by its `save()` method. This is fine when you're generating the tokens manually but in a migration, where you're referencing the model via `apps.get_model()`, [none of the custom model methods are available](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#historical-models).

So what's happening is that the tokens are being generated with empty keys. The first one will work but all after that will generate this error because the key is not unique.

A simple workaround is to just copy the code that DRF uses to generate the key into your migration. Something like this should work:

```
for user in User.objects.using(db_alias).all():
    key = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()
    Token.objects.using(db_alias).get_or_create(user=user, key=key)
```